# Scheme Descending order

Tags: recursion, scheme

I'm new to scheme, so I apologize for the elementary question ahead of time. I'm trying to create a recursive descending list. Currently it returns `(1 2 3)` instead of `(3 2 1)`

I think the problem is, is that I'm placing my new element at the front instead of the end of the list. However, I'm not quite sure how to get it as I keep getting errors when I try.

Here's what I have so far:

```
(define (descend N mylist)  
  (if (= N 0) mylist
      (descend (- N 1) (cons N mylist))))

(descend 3 '())
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the `mylist` argument is wholly unnecessary. It's never anything but the empty list, so it can simply be omitted.

Second of all, if you don't need your function to be tail recursive, then simply reorder the structure of your calls to `cons` and `descend` so that the list is built in the opposite direction.

```
(define (descend N)
  (if (= N 0) '()
      (cons N (descend (- N 1)))))
```

If you need a tail-recursive version, then it would probably make more sense to create an accumulator with a helper loop and simply iterate in reverse.

```
(define (descend N)
  (let loop ((x 1)
             (acc '()))
    (if (= x N) (cons x acc)
        (loop (+ x 1) (cons x acc)))))
```

Comment: Thanks Alexis for your help - I agree I like your first solution. It is clean and simple. However, I do have a requirement to have my function be - "element, list" and to have it be tail-recursion. That's why I had the "mylist". Do you have any suggestions to meet that requirement?

Comment: @user3281388 Can you clarify what the second parameter is supposed to do? Is it always just supposed to be the tail of the generated list?

Comment: The way I understand it is that the list will be what is finally returned. I pass in an int, then it returns a descending list.

Comment: @user3281388 Yes, that makes sense, but that doesn't explain why the second argument is required.

Comment: I thought with tail recursion was suppose to have 2 parameters. Also, with this particular problem, it said to "make a function so that this `(descend 3 '( ) )` would return `(3 2 1)` "

Comment: @user3281388 Well, if you wanted, you could add a dummy parameter to my second solution, which would accommodate your requirements. I don't think the second parameter makes very much sense, though.

Comment: Okay - thanks for your help. I agree the second parameter doesn't make much sense.